# How to use WindowsCommunityToolkit TextBoxMask properly?

Tags: uwp, uwp-xaml, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to use TextBoxMask from WindowsCommunityToolkit but i have some strange behaviors.
XAML code :

```
<TextBox    extensions:TextBoxMask.Mask="99/99/9999"
    Text="{Binding PatientItem.StringBirthDate, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

PatientItemViewModel code :

```
private string _StringBirthDate;
public string StringBirthDate
{
    get { return _StringBirthDate; }
    set
    {
        DateTime birthDateValue;
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(value) && DateTime.TryParse(value, out birthDateValue))
        {
            this.CalculateAgeValue(birthDateValue);
            this.BirthDate = birthDateValue;
            SetProperty(ref _StringBirthDate, value);
        }
    }
}
```

When i start from en empty input, i have no problems.
Problems appeares when i open a page to edit data : PatientItem.StringBirthDate is set with "18/02/1952" value.

When i display my page, everything seems good :

[image]

But if click on cross to clean textbox, or if i use backspace keyboard touch, only last letter dissapear, and after that moment, if i tap anything on keyboard, some strange behviors appear (number not replaced, cursor do not move forward, etc...)

[image]

Do you have any idea to improve my code  ?
Is there a known problem with text binding used with mask ?

**EDIT :** video to show more explicitely my problem :
[image]

It seems that TextBoxMask call set method with strange values :

[image]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/textboxmask

Answer (score 1):

It's default behavior if you use 'TextBoxMask' extension in your textbox. TextBoxMask will handle your TextBox's TextChanging event. See the [source code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/Extensions/TextBoxMask/TextBoxMask.cs#L226), you would know the reason. When you click the 'x' button, it will trigger the TextChanging event.

Here, I suggested that you could use <kbd>Backspace</kbd> to delete your text instead of click 'x' button. About the 'x' button, you could do not show it by applying your custom style for your textbox. See the [TextBoxMask XAML Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/extensions/textboxmask) document, it also makes custom style for the textbox.

```
<Style x:Key="MaskedTextBoxStyle"
           TargetType="TextBox">
        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,0,10,0" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top" />
        <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap" />
</Style>
```

Comment: Thanks Xavier Xie for your answer.
But i don't think problem is from 'x' button. In fact, when i use it from empty input (first use), i don't have problem even if i click on 'x' button.
But after, saving it and if i come from edition page, input is already set, and after that moment i have many dificulties. I updated my answer with new elements to show you my problems

Comment: @GeoffreyLalloué My meaning was to tell you that the all behaviors that you see are handled in TextBox's TextChanging event of TextBoxMask's [source code](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI/Extensions/TextBoxMask/TextBoxMask.cs#L226). You could download the source code to  debug and change the code to change these behaviors.